# Is it possible to keep Django Admin Panel accesible in production mode? (DEBUG=False)

Tags: django, django-models, deployment, django-admin

I am developing a webpage for my college where we will show ouur investigations, to solve that i decided to use the admin panel. The problem is that when I deply in production the webage I get a 500 Bad request

[I have left the deault admin path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iClLM.png)

[Also changed the path for admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJCaV.png) and still having the same issue

Comment: Normally there is no restriction about serving an admin page in production. Did you clear the cookies, etc. Try visiting it with a "fresh browser".

Comment: Yes, i have clean the cookies but it stills without allowing me

Answer (score 0):

Try opening on a different browser like chrome etc

Comment: I also have try it